# send"LShift+ctrl" and "rshift+ctrl" and detect in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I detect "LShift" and "rshift" with these codes:

```
if ((GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey) < 0))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Left Shift");
}
if ((GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey) < 0))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Right Shift");
}
```

but I cannot detect "LShift+ctrl" and "rshift+ctrl" .How can I detect?
also when pressctrl+leftshift on keyboard the richtextbox direction change and for this Process I use this code:

```
SendKeys.Send("+^");
```

but this code work like leftshift+ctrl and i need rightshift+ctrl.How can I send rightshift+ctrl?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SendKeys.Send("(+^)");
```

Comment: This code worke like SendKeys.Send("+^"); I want send rightshift+ctrl thanks for yout help